# Converting graphics with ExportString

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Can ExportString export an EMF or GIF? In this demo streamoutput.emf somehow gets mangled:

```
Quiet[DeleteFile["C:\\Temp\\thisworks.emf"]];
Quiet[DeleteFile["C:\\Temp\\streamoutput.emf"]];

graphic = Graphics[{Thick, Red, Circle[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[4],
    Black, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}}]}];
Export["C:\\Temp\\thisworks.emf", graphic, "EMF"];

file = ExportString[graphic, "EMF"];
stream = OpenWrite["C:\\Temp\\streamoutput.emf", BinaryFormat -> True];
Write[stream, file];
Close[stream];
```

If ExportString worked I might be able to use it to transfer EMFs through NETLink, e.g.

```
kernel.Compute("ExportString[Graphics[Rectangle[]], \"EMF\"]");
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Temp\\output.emf", kernel.Result.ToString());
```

**Addendum**

Got that working.

```
kernel.Compute("ExportString[Graphics[Rectangle[]],{\"Base64\",\"EMF\"}]");
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(kernel.Result.ToString());
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\output.emf", decodedBytes);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the looks of it, `Write` includes the quotation marks of the string `file` when writing to `stream`, so the output file starts with something like `"GIF....` instead of just `GIF...`. When using `BinaryWrite` instead of `Write` it does seem to work. For example

```
file = ExportString[graphic, "GIF"];
stream = OpenWrite["streamoutput.gif", BinaryFormat -> True];
BinaryWrite[stream, file];
Close[stream];
Import["streamoutput.gif"]
```

produces

[image: streamoutput]

So `ExportString` does produce a valid string for GIF at least. I don't have windows so I can't test for EMF.

Comment: I confirmed that this solution works for EMF on Windows as well.