# How can i write to file in binary code at Wolfram mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I trying to write to file in binary code.
In mathematica i have some sting that i encoded with huffman code , i need to write them to binary file and see what is the file size.

what is the best way to do it?

thanks.

Comment: if you have any doubt why im using wolfarm mathematica , its for my home work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this procedure for your purpose. Here some binary data is created in `file` and written out in binary format to `streamoutput.gif`:

```
file = ExportString[Graphics[Disk[]], "GIF"];
stream = OpenWrite["streamoutput.gif", BinaryFormat -> True];
BinaryWrite[stream, file];
Close[stream];
Import["streamoutput.gif"]
```

source:
[Converting graphics with ExportString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755810/converting-graphics-with-exportstring/7756421#7756421)